# How to get id (string) of view using view.getId() inside Android Espresso custom matcher?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I need to get id (string) of view inside custom Espresso matcher. I need to write into log something like `with id: com.domain:id/et_name`.

I have tried to use: `Resources.getSystem().getResourceName(textView.getId());`, but it returns `null`.

**What is way to get id inside espresso matcher ?**

Comment: textView.getId() - are you sure that view has an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to get view id (string): `textView.getResources().getResourceName(textView.getId());` , but looks like espresso not allowing to write a log -:(